# How can I understand the behavior of pipe, with varying data flow?

Tags: c, linux, unix, pipe, pipeline

My problem is a bit hard to explain properly as I do not understand fully the behavior behind it.
I have been working on pipe and pipelines in C, and I noticed some behavior that is a bit mysterious to me.

Let's take a few example: Let's try to pipe yes with head. (yes  | head). Even though I coded the behavior in a custom program, I don't understand how the pipe knows when to stop piping ? It seems two underlying phenomenons are causing this (maybe), the SIGPIPE and/or the internal size a pipe can take. How does the pipe stop piping, is it when it's full ? But the size of a pipe is way superior to 10 "yes\n" no ? And SIGPIPE only works when the end read/write is closed no ?

Also let's take another example, for example cat and ls: cat | ls or even cat | cat | ls.
It seems the stdin of the pipe is waiting for input, but how does it know when to stop, i.e. after one input ? What are the mechanism that permits this behavior?

Also can anyone provide me with others examples of these very specific behavior if there are any in pipes and pipelines so I can get an good overview of theses mechanism ?

In my own implementation, I managed to replicate that behavior using waitpid. However how does the child process itself know when to stop ? Is it command specific ?

Comment: Beej's guide to UNIX IPC explains it very well: https://beej.us/guide/bgipc/

Comment: Or perhaps go straight to *"Unix Network Programming: Interprocess Communication*".

Comment: The pipe has a buffer. When a process writes into the pipe, if it fills the buffer, the process is blocked from continuing to execute. When a process reads from the pipe, if the buffer is empty, the process is blocked from continuing. When a process reading from the pipe changes a full buffer to a not-full buffer, processes that were blocked due to writing to a full buffer are unblocked, so they can write more. When a process writing to the pipe changes an empty buffer to a not-empty buffer, processes that were blocked due to reading from an empty buffer are unblocked, so they can read more.

Comment: It's cats all the way down.

Answer (score 2):

The `write` operation will block when the pipe buffer is full, the `read` operation will block when the buffer is empty.

When the write end of the pipe is closed, the reading process will get an EOF indication after reading all data from the buffer. Many programs will terminate in this case.

When the read end of the pipe is closed, the writing process will get a SIGPIPE. This will also terminate most programs.

When you run `cat | ls`, STDOUT of `cat` is connected to STDIN of `ls`, but `ls` does not read from STDIN. On the system where I checked this, `ls` simply ignores STDIN and the file descriptor will be closed when `ls` terminates.

You will see the output of `ls`, and `cat` will be waiting for input.

`cat` will not write anything to STDOUT before it has read enough data from STDIN, so it will not notice that the other end of the pipe has been closed.

`cat` will terminate when it detects EOF on STDIN which can be done by pressing CTRL+D or by redirecting STDIN from `/dev/null`, or when it gets SIGPIPE after trying to write to the pipe which will happen when you (type something and) press ENTER.

You can see the behavior with `strace`.

`cat` terminates after EOF on input which is shown as `read(0, ...)` returning 0.

```
strace cat < /dev/null | ls
```

`cat` killed by SIGPIPE.

```
strace cat < /dev/zero | ls
```

Answer (score 1):

> How does the pipe stop piping

The pipe stops piping when either end is closed.

If the input(write) end of the pipe is closed, then any data in the pipe is held until it is read from the output end.  Once the buffer is emptied, anyone subsequently reading from the output end will get an EOF.

If the output(read) end of the pipe is closed, any data in the pipe will be discarded.  Anyone subsequently writing to the input end will get a SIGPIPE/EPIPE.  Note that a process merely holding open the input but not actively writing to it will *not* be signalled.

So when you type `cat | ls` you get a `cat` program with stdout connected to the input of the pipe and `ls` with stdin connected to the output.  `ls` runs and outputs some stuff (to its stdout, which is still the terminal) and never reads from stdin.  Once done it exits and closes the output of the pipe.  Meanwhile `cat` is waiting for input from its stdin (the terminal).  When it gets it (you type a line), it writes it to stdout, gets a SIGPIPE/EPIPE and exits (discarding the data as there's noone to write it to.)  This closes the input of the pipe, so the pipe goes away now that both ends have been closed.

Now lets look at what happens with `cat | cat | ls`.  You now have two pipes and two cat programs.  As before `ls` runs and exits, closing the output of the second pipe.  Now you type a line and the first cat reads it and copies it to the first pipe (still fully open) where the second cat reads it and copies it to the second pipe (which has its output closed), so it (the second cat) gets a SIGPIPE/EPIPE and exits (which closes the output of the first pipe).  At this point the first cat is still waiting for input, so if you type a second line, it copies that to the now closed first pipe and gets a SIGPIPE/EPIPE and exits

Comment: Sorry, but if you pipe `cat` output to `ls` you will get nothing but an `ls` listing, shouldn't you mount the pipe in reverse, to `cat` the output of `ls`.

Comment: While it doesn't make a lot of sense to pipe something to the input of `ls`, the question is about the weird behavior one sees when you do that.  It makes perfect sense if you understand how pipes work.

Comment: Ah, ok... I was not following completely why should you do that... but now I understand.  You want to trigger the SIGPIPE signal to the cat instances. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

> How does the pipe stop piping, is it when it's full ?

A pipe has several states:

1. if you obtain the pipe through a call to `pipe(2)` (an unnamed pipe) both file descriptors are already open, so this doesn't apply to it (you start in point 2. below).  When you open a named pipe, your `open(2)` call (depending if you have open with `O_READ`, `O_WRITE`, or `O_RDWR`.  The pipe has two sides, the writer and the reader side.  When you open it, you attach to the sides, depending on how do you open it.  Well, up to here, the pipe blocks any `open(2)` call, until both sides have at least one process tied to them.  So, if you open a pipe and `read(2)` from it, then your open will be blocked, until other process has opened it to read.
2. once both extremes have it open, the readers (the process issuing a `read(2)` call) block when the pipe is empty, and the writers (the processes issuing a `write(2)` call) block whenever the write call cannot be satisfied due to fillin completely the pipe.  Old implementations of pipes used the filesystem to hold the data, and the data was stored only in the direct addressed disk blocks.  This meant (as there are 10 such blocks in an inode) that you normally had space in the pipe to hold 10 blocks, after that, the writers are blocked.  Later, pipes were implemented using the socket infrastructure in BSD systems, which allowed you to control the buffer size with `ioctl(2)` calls.  Today, IMHO, pipes use a common implementation, that is separate from sockets also.
3. When the processes close the pipe continues to work as said in point 2. above, until the number of readers/writers collapses to zero.  At that point, the pipe starts giving End Of File condition to all readers (this means `read(2)` syscall will return 0 bytes, without blocking) and error (cannot write to pipe) to writers.  In addition, the kernel sends a signal (which normally aborts the writer processes) `SIGPIPE`  to every process that has the pipe open for writing.  If you have not ignored that signal or you have not installed a signal handler for it, your process will die.  In this state, it's impossible to reopen the pipe again, until all processes have closed it.

A common error is when you `pipe()` or you open a pipe with `O_RDWR`, and the other process closes its file descriptor, and you don't get anything indicating about the other's close call..... this is due to the thing that both sides of the pipe are still open (by the same process) so it will not receive anything because it can still write to the pipe.

Any other kind of misbehaviour could be explained if you had posted any code, but you didn't, so IMHO, thi answer is still incomplete, but the number of different scenarios is difficult to enumerate, so I'll be pendant of any update to your question with some faulty (or needed of explanation) code.